# Using getters in the Angular component html template

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a data model class, let say:

```
class Question {
    body: string;
    
    get bodyForTableRow(): string {
        return this.body.replace("\n", " // ");
    }
}
```

And in the component html template I use the following declaration to evaluate the getter value:

```
 {{ oneQuestion.bodyForTableRow }}
```

But instead of value, where new lines are replace with `//` symbols I get an empty string.

When I use

```
 {{ oneQuestion.body }}
```

it displays the body contents.

Why does it happen? Should I always use a *real* fields to map them to the html-components and getters are not suitable for this case?

---

UPDATE

When the declaration in the template looks like that

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <!-- other columns skipped --> 

  <ng-container matColumnDef="body">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Question Body</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let oneQuestion">
      {{ oneQuestion.body }}
    </td>
  </ng-container>
</table>
```

It displays the `body` content in the every table row. But when I use this code:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <!-- other columns skipped --> 

  <ng-container matColumnDef="body">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Question Body</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let oneQuestion">
      {{ oneQuestion.bodyForTableRow }}
    </td>
  </ng-container>
</table>
```

It shows empty rows.

---

UPDATE 2

Question data model class declared like that:

```
export class QuestionDataModel {
  body: string; // public access field for template
  
  constructor(bodyValue: string) {
    this.body = bodyValue;
  }  
  
}
```

Data source is declared like that:

```
  dataSource: QuestionDataModel[];
```

I populate the datasource via rest-call

```
const url: string = `/questions/all`;
this.http.get(url).subscribe(
  (data: QuestionDataModel[]) => {
    this.dataSource = data;
  },
  (error) => this.reportServerError(error)
);
```

Comment: Are you actually creating instances of `Question` classes?  Just using type assertion will not create an instance of `Question`, and you won't have access to getters/setters/other methods.

Comment: @cjd82187 I've posted update to my question. Does it clarify it ?

Comment: @Rafael no the update does not clarify, we'd need to see how you're fetching and creating the `dataSource` in this case. Seems like something suspect is happening there.

Comment: @bryan60 I will update my question soon. Thanks.

Comment: @bryan60 I've updated my question again.

Comment: yea, it's as @cjd82187, you're not actually instantiating classes, you're just declaring a type, which doesn't work. To have access to getters and setters, you need to declare your classes with the `new` keyword as in my answer.

Comment: classes are instantiated automatically when I read rest-call response and dataSource is being populated with instances of this class, is not it ?

Comment: no they're not. That's what we're saying, classes do not just automatically get instantiated. Types are inferred from your typings, but that's not the same as instantiating a class. you MUST manually instantiate your classes with the `new` keyword to use class features. As a best practice, when typing responses, only ever use interfaces to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you're doing should work, you've got some other issue going on like not instantiating your class correctly maybe, but you probably really want to restructure to use a setter instead...

```
class Question {
    private _body: string;

    set body(body: string) {
      this.bodyForTableRow = body.replace("\n", " // ");
      this._body = body;
    }
    get body() {
      return this._body;
    }
    
    bodyForTableRow: string;
}
```

the way angular change detection works, it evaluates functions on every change detection cycle which can be pretty frequent, so by putting that `replace` in a getter, you're running it on every single cycle. With this structure, you're just running and setting it when you need to.

To use this or any class, you need to use the `new` keyword,

```
this.oneQuestion = new Question();
this.oneQuestion.body = 'my string with line returns \n next line';
```

Comment: the point of my question is, should I have a "real" field to store a value, like you declared `bodyForTableRow: string`, or having a getter could be sufficient. As far as I understand having only getter, that calculates its value using `body` field does not work. I should save processed data to another real field and use it. Am I right?

Comment: both ways should work, but using a "real" field is far more efficient and performs much better. You have another issue unrelated to your getter causing the problem.

Comment: thank you, I understand, that pre-calculated field should perform better. I am just wondering why this getter does not work in my case. What is wrong with my approach. I have some experience with Java/C# and as far as I understand, if I have a class instance, I can use a getter to get a calculated value, based on this class instance. Why not in this case?

Comment: the problem is that you're not creating class instances anywhere with the `new` keyword. you're just declaring types, it doesn't work that way, you need to actually create classes. TS is taking you're word for it that you're not lying to it, but you are.

Comment: Honestly I don't get the point, why do I don't instantiate class. When I call rest endpoint I get response with an array of class instances and I just assign dataSource with the received `data`. And it works ok, when I don't use getters and only real fields.

Comment: because getters are a class feature that requires you to instantiate a class. you DO NOT have an array of class instances. you have an array of objects with none of the associated class features you expect, and that you are lying to typescript about the type of,